# Code refactoring for environment conditional in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, refactoring, sidekiq

In my Rails app, I am using sidekiq for job scheduling to lift heavy tasks. So, I have this code in a lot of places:

```
if Rails.env.development? or Rails.env.test?
   #Call the method directly
else #Rails.env.production?
   #Call the job via sidekiq that calls the said method
end
```

Is there any way to clean this out? I am reading software design patterns these days. I am not able to apply that knowledge here. Can you suggest how can this be cleaned up or written in a way that is more manageable?

Comment: There's no generic answer--it depends on the nature of what's being called, whether it's part of a class hierarchy, etc. Seems like some form of mixin could wrap this up, though, e.g., a form of `sidekiqable :the_method` wrapper.

Comment: Have you thought about using just jobs? You can set different job runners according to your env (sidekiq for prod, async for dev & test for test) to achieve similar behaviour and there would be less environment specific code which is less error-prone. I guess right now your tests are checking method calls, but what happens if your job changes and you forget to update? All test passes but your actual production code breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can put

```rb
require 'sidekiq/testing'
Sidekiq::Testing.inline!
```

in your `development.rb` and `test.rb` config files to get the behaviour you are after. In your applications business logic you would remove the environment conditional and just call the worker (which will now run synchronously in test and development).

Answer (score -1):

How about trying refactoring like following?

```
module Util
  extend self

  def execute_method_or_delay_its_execution(obj:, method_name:)
    if Rails.env.development? or Rails.env.test?
       obj.send(method_name)
    else #Rails.env.production?
       #Call the job via sidekiq that calls the said method
    end
  end
end

MyClass1
  def my_method
    Util.execute_method_or_delay_its_execution(obj: self, method_name: :my_method)
  end
end

MyClass2
  def my_method
    Util.execute_method_or_delay_its_execution(obj: self, method_name: :my_method)
  end
end
```

and then just invoke the methods on object as it should be and the internal delegation should take care of your desired direct execution or delayed execution

```
mc_1 = MyClass1.new
mc_1.my_method

mc_2 = MyClass2.new
mc_2.my_method
```

Hope that helps. Thanks.

Comment: Having the conditional that calls the method directly opposed to going through a worker is a very dangerous game to play if your engineering team is not very on top of things because methods / services will interface differently depending on your environment. For example, in production the output of this method would be a string (the sidekiq job), whereas in development / test the output of this method would be whatever the sent method returns.